# Why does synchronous lambda invoke multiple times?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have a lambda function `my-func` which should only be run once at a time. Because of that, I set the Reserved Concurrency to 1. I am trying to invoke it with the command:

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name my-func --invocation-type RequestResponse --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{\"recreate\":true}' response.json
```

However, it results in this error after a few seconds:

```
An error occurred (TooManyRequestsException) when calling the Invoke operation (reached max retries: 2): Rate Exceeded.
```

It appears that it tries to invoke the function multiple times even though the original invocation never ran into an error. If I increase the Reserved Concurrency to a value like 5, then the single `lambda invoke` command results in multiple invocations even though the first invocation continues to execute without any problem.

Another thing that is throwing me off is that it works correctly from the AWS console GUI. I created a test event in the AWS lambda function on the console interface. It invokes `my-func` with the same payload I am using in the aws-cli command:

```
{
  "recreate": true
}
```

Invoking the function using this test event works flawlessly. It seems to just run the function once and doesn't cause a TooManyRequestsException. Does this mean something is wrong with my aws-cli command?

Comment: What is your function code? Maybe you try to run it recursively?

Comment: @Marcin I thought about that at first, but the function doesn't call itself anywhere. In fact it doesn't perform any lambda operations. It only configures some NAT gateway stuff using ec2 client in boto3

Comment: It does not have to be explicit invocation. Maybe the function triggers something non-directly (e.g. store object in S3 and S3 event triggers the same function).

Comment: @Marcin I just did a test: I removed all code from the function and replaced it with time.sleep(60). Again, the function works correctly when I invoke it from the AWS console but gets TooManyRequestsException when I invoke from the aws-cli. Could it be something with the way I'm invoking it?

Comment: Can you post `--debug` logs?

Comment: What does your Lambda function do? The throttling could be related to API calls that the Lambda function itself makes. Does CloudWatch show Lambda function throttle metrics?

Comment: @jellycsc [Here is the debug output](https://pastebin.com/raw/6843QkpC)

Comment: The strange thing is that even after the cli responds with the TooManyRequestsException, the lambda is still actually running and finishes successfully around a minute later.

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out the problem. Even though my function's timeout was set to 600 (5 minutes), the aws cli has it's own socket timeout which defaults to 60 seconds. Each time it reached this timeout, it must have triggered a retry. I fixed it by adding `--cli-read-timeout 600` to my command like so:

```
aws --cli-read-timeout 600 lambda invoke --function-name my-func --invocation-type RequestResponse --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{\"recreate\":true}' response.json
```

Comment: Why would read take more than 60 seconds? Does the function have a large output and you have a slow connection?

Comment: @jellycsc He mentioned that the lambda modifies NAT gateway resources. Creating NAT gateways is a slow operation that can easily take 60+ seconds.  
It is simply a very slow operation ion the AWS side.    
So this has nothing to do with his connection, it is working as expected.

Comment: Thank You for that! when doing and invoke through e.g. python boto library the same aplies, the timeout can be changed in the config: https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html

Comment: Good find. I am seeing the same thing with lambda  execution > 60 seconds.